# Python - Regex capturing a word right after a specfic word

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to regex search location in a document. However, I am having trouble with capturing ***only*** the location part of the text.

For example, for the text:  `LOCATION   03-ED-50-39.5/48.7  DIVISION HIGHWAY ROAD   44 CONTRACT ITEMS`, we would only want `LOCATION    03-ED-50-39.5/48.7`.

Currently, I have the following code:

```
LOCATION\s+(\d+)
```

We know that the location string starts with a digit and ends with a digit with no space. Is there a way to capture the entire word/string right next to the location? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `\S` matches a non-whitespace if this if of help ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/rzhj9A/1)).

Comment: What tool or language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Python` (using `positive look behind`):

```
import re
s = 'LOCATION   03-ED-50-39.5/48.7  DIVISION HIGHWAY ROAD   44 CONTRACT ITEMS'
pattern = '(?<=LOCATION\s{3})\S+'
matches = re.finditer(pattern, s)
for match in matches:
    print(match.group())
```

### Output

```
03-ED-50-39.5O/48.7
```

### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `(?<=` | [look behind](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) to see if there is: |
| `LOCATION` | 'LOCATION' |
| `\s{3}` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (3 times) |
| `)` | end of look-behind |
| `\S+` | non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

Comment: How do you know the OP is using `grep` or that `\K` is available?